# Bootstrap 3 page cover with Fixed navbar and Sticky footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sticky-footer, cover

I am trying to make a web page using Bootstrap 3 page cover with Fixed navbar and Sticky footer

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

The problem is that Sticky footer is conflict with the cover and missing is up :(

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
....
</nav>
Cover dynamic content
<sticky footer>
```

Comment: Hi, what you tried? Can you post your code? And please take a look how ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I try merge all the 3 bootstrap examples into one.
But I see later that cover is conflict with sticky-footer

because sticky footer css code position relative :
`html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}`

Thank you